# angular: How to mock extends class in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I've a injectable service (EntityApi) which extends a class (BaseApi). In my spec I like to mock the BaseApi with BaseApiStub. But it vain. Always calling the EntityApi.

```js
// class
export class BaseApi { // want to mock BaseApi
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
       console.log("Should not be here...");
    }
}

// service
@Injectable()
export class EntityApi extends BaseApi {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
       super(injector, "entity");
    }
}

// component
@Component({
  selector: 'rt-entity-list',
  templateUrl: './entity-list.component.html',
})
export class EntityListComponent {
  api: any;
  constructor(public entityApi: EntityApi) { 
    this.api = entityApi;
  }
}

// mock api
export class BaseApiStub { //mocked api
    constructor() {
      console.log("You are on track!!")
    }
    get() { }
}

// spec
describe('EntityListComponent', () => {
  let component: EntityListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EntityListComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EntityListComponent],
      providers: [ { provide: BaseApi, useClass: BaseApiStub }, // mocked class.
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
    
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EntityListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Expected Behavior is, while compile component in spec. It should call the BaseApiStub, instead it is calling BaseApi. I've seen a solution as below. But no luck.

```
export class BaseApiStub extends BaseApi { }
```

> Test Code: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-zaulhn) Check the console. I expect the **You are
>   on track!!** log but received as **Should not be here...**

Not able to progress further. Can someone correct my mistake please.

Comment: Hi Premkumar, your approach is correct, but did you provide any fake / mock implementation for BaseApi methods in your BaseApiStub? (cause according to your snippet it is empty)

Comment: I've added a method inside BaseApiStub. Still facing same issue. It is calling BaseApi. Is the class mock syntax is correct? Usually, for service I used to mock like this. But not sure about class.

Comment: it depends on conditions of your test of course, e.g. if both BaseApi and BaseApiStub are available in your injector it will just resolve the first one found.
try to override your provider directly just to be sure, like this:
TestBed.overrideProvider(BaseApi, BaseApiStub)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. Still the call is going wrong. I've updated my question with the stackblitz. Unit test is passing. But it should not call BaseApi. Check the console.

Comment: now its clear, you do register a real Api first, then you provide another instance, do just this providers: [{ provide: EntityApi, useClass: BaseApiStub }]

Comment: `EntityApi` is the one will be generated outside code. So I should write test to check whether the EntityApi is available or not. like. `    expect(component.api.__proto__.constructor.name).toBe('EntityApi');`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not work. Dependency injection and class inheritance are not directly related. This means you cannot switch out the base class of your service like this.

As I see it you have two ways on how to do this.

**Option 1:**

Instead of mocking your BaseApi and providing the mock in your test you need to mock your EntityApi and provide this mock in your test.

**Option 2:**

Instead of letting your EntityApi extend from BaseApi, you could keep BaseApi a simple service and provide it as a dependency.

Instead of

```
class EntityApi extends BaseApi {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
```

you do

```
class EntityApi {
    constructor(private api: BaseApi) {
```

If you setup your EntityApi like this, it does not extend from BaseApi, but rather  has it as a dependency. Then you can create a mock of the BaseApi and provide it like you did in your test.

**Edit**

Regarding your comment:

> Since I should be using methods from BaseApi I cannot go without extends.

This is not true. Let's say the BaseApi has a method foo() that you want to use. When you extend your baseclass, the usage might look like this:

```
class EntityApi extends BaseApi {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
    exampleMethod() {
        this.foo();
    }
}
```

If you just have the dependency you can still call the method like this:

```
class EntityApi {
    constructor(private api: BaseApi) {}
    exampleMethod() {
        this.api.foo();
    }
}
```

You don't need to extend from BaseApi in order to call methods on it.

Comment: I feel like, both the options will not suit for my requirement. EntityApi will be generated dynamically. i.e., I've a generator to generate api for all my table. e.g. CompanyApi, DepartmentApi, so on. All the Api will extends with BaseApi. BaseApi got some reusable methods.

Comment: I should write a test to check whether the generated api is available or not. something like `expect(component.api.__proto__.constructor.name).toBe('EntityApi');`. So option 1 will not work out. Since I should be using methods from BaseApi I cannot go without extends.

Comment: It should not matter if you need to call methods on the base api, as long as you have control over the templates of your generator. I added an example on how to call them in my answer.

Comment: I agreed your point. I'm trying to avoid `this.api.foo()`. want to access as `this.foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to mock a method of a parent class (e.g for Directive) you can do that through the stub extension of the tested class.

```
spyObject = {
  methodToSpyOn(){}
};

@Directive({selector: '[myDirective]'})
class MyStubDirective extends MyDirective {
  parentMethodToMock() {
    return spyObject.methodToSpyOn();
  }
}

spyOn(spyObject, 'methodToSpyOn').and.returnValue(true);
```

This approach is usually needed if your class has the parent method calls in constructor